# Resharper completion without overwriting existing code

Tags: resharper

In Resharper when I go back to edit some existing code.. eg. wanting to insert a String.Format into this code:

```
<td>
    <%= Html.Encode(item.Address) %>
</td>
```

I move the cursor to before 'item' and type in 'String.F', getting Resharper's intellisense completion list that includes the 'Format' method.

However if I press <kbd>TAB</kbd> then it replaces 'item' with '.Format()'

Is there a way to use completing without replacing the existing text?

Comment: Resharper is great, it *almost* turns Visual Studio into IntelliJ ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two techniques you can use.

The first is to use the Enter key, the second is to pop a space between where you are going to start typing and the next bit of code, which will prevent the next bit of code from being overwritten.

Comment: Down-side of the space technique is that you then have to hit the back-arrow.

Answer (score 10):

Stumbled upon using <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>TAB</kbd> to choose from the completion list. That does exactly what I want. It surrounds (in this case) 'item.Address' with the String.Format( .. ).

Answer (score 5):

There is an actual setting now to disable this (annoying) behavior.

Go to the Options dialog (Menu -> Resharper -> Options).
In this Options dialog go to Environment -> IntelliSense -> Completion Characters.

Here you can set the Tab behavior to Insert instead of Replace.

[Screenshot of Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhbsQ.png)

[Resharper documentation about Completing Characters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Options__Environment__Completing_Characters.html)

This is an addition to the answer in 2010, for everyone that reaches this post via populair search engines ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `String.Format` surround template but you may have to map a hotkey to it for easier access.

Comment: You are right, though I was really thinking of the more general case - String.Format was just a good example.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard command you want to use is called: `Resharper_ForceCompleteItem`.  So if you go into Visual Studio's Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard you could assign a keyboard shortcut there.  Not sure if it would be possible to use <kbd>Tab</kbd>, though.