# Change resharper autocomplete behavior

Tags: resharper

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706632/resharper-completion-without-overwriting-existing-code), it was established that <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> have two distinct behaviors for Resharper's intellisense autocomplete.  Is there any way to swap them?  Or set the tab key's behavior to the same as <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

I'm currently using Resharper 6.1 in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899190/tab-behavior-resharper-intellisense-options/8901513#8901513), there's no way to swap them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest ReSharper (2016.x) has such option. Go to ReSharper -> Options -> Environment -> IntelliSense -> Completing Characters and on the top of the window select the behavior for "Enter Key" and "Tab Key". You can swap behavior or change both to be same.